# CakePHP: Date Range

Tags: cakephp

Is there a better way for me to calculate the following (I'm trying to pull all "Action Items"  from yesterday and store them in "paste_due", and all action items for today and store them in "today") - This is inside of my "Agents" controller (Agent 'hasMany' ActionItem and ActionItem 'belongsTo' Agent):

```
public function planner() {

    $yesterday = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime("yesterday"));
    $conditions = array('ActionItem.due <' => $yesterday, 'ActionItem.agent_id' => '1');
    $this->set('past_due', $this->Agent->ActionItem->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions)));

    $today = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("today"));
    $today_end = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime("today"));
    $conditions = array('ActionItem.due >' => $today, 'ActionItem.due <' => $today_end, 'ActionItem.agent_id' => '1');
    $this->set('today', $this->Agent->ActionItem->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions)));
}
```

The above works, but I'm not for sure if it's the best way to go about i..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be room for some improvement (though as you say, the current code should work, so it's just some of my thoughts).

First of all, if you're only going to check against times like `00:00:00` and `23:59:59`, drop the times altogether and just use a `DATE` field rather than a `DATETIME` field. It makes checking much easier as you don't have to worry about times. (If the times are essential for other parts of your application, then the below example code should be adjusted accordingly.)

Furthermore I'd use the [**DateTime**](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) functions of PHP rather than the `date()` with `strtotime()`, mainly because it's pretty much a habit of mine whenever I work with date/time data. This is because DateTime adds a lot of possibilities and flexibility to your date and time data without too much hassle. Something like this is what I'd probably go for:

```
public function planner() {

    // Set the DateTime object (defaults to current date/time)
    $today = new DateTime();

    // Overdue actions (everything older than today)
    $overdue = $this->Agent->ActionItem->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            // Check due against a 'Y-m-d' formatted date of today.
            'ActionItem.due <' => $today->format('Y-m-d'),
            'ActionItem.agent_id' => '1'
        )
    ));

    // Actions due today (or in the future)
    $due = $this->Agent->ActionItem->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            // Check due against a 'Y-m-d' formatted date of today.
            'ActionItem.due >=' => $today->format('Y-m-d'),
            'ActionItem.agent_id' => '1'
        )
    ));

    // Set the items
    $this->set(compact('overdue', 'due'));
}
```