# Find within date range

Tags: cakephp, date-range, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to find all services for each customer in a monthly date range.
Following this answered question [CakePHP: Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285139/cakephp-date-range) I created this code in my summaries controller:

```
      public function view($id=null) {
            //other code
            $this->loadModel('Event');
            $summary = $this->Summary->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Summary.id' => $id)));
            $first = date('m-01-Y', strtotime($summary['Summary']['date']));

            //added this for debugging and the value is the date i want
            $this->set('first', $first);

            $last = date('m-t-Y', strtotime($summary['Summary']['date']));

            //debugging, this works too
            $this->set('last', $last);

            $conditions = array("'Event.start' >=" => $first, "'Event.start' <=" => $last,
                                'Event.customer_id' => 'Summary.customer_id'
                               );
            $this->set('events', $this->Event->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions)));
```

But the $events variable in my view is empty. I also tried to eliminate the customer_id condition to test the date ranges, and the problem seems to be that 'Event.start' could not be compared properly. and date() function can't be used inside quotes. any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are adding more single quote to your query will not work

please change as below to you $conditions

```
 $conditions = array("Event.start >=" => "'".$first."'", "Event.start <=" => "'".$last."'",
                                'Event.customer_id' => 'Summary.customer_id'
                               );
```

Please let me know if i can help you more

```
$summary['Summary']['date'] = '4-5-2013'; // where format is 'd-m-Y';

$first = date('m-01-Y H:i:s', strtotime($summary['Summary']['date']));

echo "first".$first;
echo "<br>date is -> ". date('m-t-Y');
```

**output like**

```
first05-01-2013 00:00:00
date is -> 05-31-2013
```

so you can compare date

Comment: oh.. maybe you got it. the format of event.start is datetime while summary.date is only a date. I'll try to change it to datetime and amend the code and i'll let you know.

Comment: modified like this: `$first = date('m-01-Y H:i:s', strtotime($summary['Summary']['date']));` but tried to debug this `strtotime('Event.start')` which result is false...

Comment: will please add your summary date here

Comment: also you have to change it same as in $last

Comment: i have updated my answer to use date in you query pls let me know

Comment: yeah i did it, but omitted, my bad. summary date is stored this way: 2013-04-02. the day can be whatever cause the month is what I need. after conversion (now i changed date format to match the Event.start, still not working): $first = 2013-04-01 00:00:00, $last = 2013-04-30 23:59:59. while an example of Event.start in my DB is: 2013-04-15 09:30:00

Comment: sorry to say again now you can use date like "'".$first."'" as i update my new answer

Comment: sorry but I couldn't understand what you want me to do.
you want me to prtint out $first with datetime format and $last in date format?

Comment: Maybe I understand. I'll try to explain in a better way. the summariescontroller function is to find and print out every event happened in a month for each customer. so Event.start is what we need to compare and Summary.date is the month/year the user's chooses to review. so If Event.start is a Datetime field, we should compare everything in datetime. Am I correct?

Comment: oh BTW i forgot to tell you, that I already debugged $first and $last in my previous comment, and they are the same format as Event.start.